# Rendering QChart without QGraphicsView

Tags: qt, qtcharts

I'd like to render `QChart` (which is `QGraphicsWidget` in its core) to specific painter, for example `QSvgGenerator`.

I've read following topic https://forum.qt.io/topic/38352/rendering-qgraphicsitem-without-qgraphicsscene/2 and implemented it in my code:

```
QBuffer b;
QSvgGenerator p;
p.setOutputDevice(&b);
QSize s = app->chart()->size().toSize();
p.setSize(s);
p.setViewBox(QRect(0,0,s.width(),s.height()));
QPainter painter;
painter.begin(&p);
painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
app->chart()->paint(&painter, 0, 0); // This gives 0 items in 1 group
m_view->render(&painter); // m_view has app->chart() in it, and this one gives right image
qDebug() << "Copied";
painter.end();
QMimeData * d = new QMimeData();
d->setData("image/svg+xml",b.buffer());
QApplication::clipboard()->setMimeData(d,QClipboard::Clipboard);
```

There are two lines with comments: first one is for painting `QChart` directly, second - rendering `QGraphicsView`.

I've already tried to play with `setViewBox`, setting it to enormous values doesn't help. The effect is the same if I use `QImage` instead of `QSvgGenerator`, I get empty picture.

So the question is why `QChart->paint()` gives me empty painting?

EDIT: working code may be found on bitbucket:  https://bitbucket.org/morodeer/charts_test_2/commits/b1eee99736beb5e43eae2a40ae116ee07e01558f

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I still don't understand what's happening deep in core, but I've found a way to make it work.

```
app->chart()->paint(&painter, 0, 0);
```

should be changed to

```
app->chart()->scene()->render(&painter, 0, 0);
```

Looks like QChart doesn't really contain anything inside of it, but adds items to parent scene. Thus if you need to render it without adding to QGraphicsView like I did, you should also create `QGraphicsScene` and add chart to it:

```
m_scene = new QGraphicsScene();
m_scene->addItem(m_chart);
```

, then you'll be able to render chart's scene.

Answer (score 2):

As this is more or less the only hint I've found about how to render charts from a QChart at all and it took me quite a while to figure it out, I tought I'd share my code.

This is python with PyQt5, but should be easily translatable to pure C++ ;)
Also note that my QChart is part of a QChartView widget.

```python
chart = QtChart.QChart()
chart_view = QtChart.QChartView(chart)

...

# the desired size of the rendering
# in pixels for PNG, in pt for SVG
output_size = QtCore.QSize(800,600)

output_rect = QtCore.QRectF(QtCore.QPointF(0,0), QtCore.QSizeF(output_size)) # cast to float

if output_svg:
    svg = QtSvg.QSvgGenerator()
    svg.setFileName(filename)
    svg.setTitle("some title")

    svg.setSize(output_size)
    svg.setViewBox(output_rect)

    canvas = svg

else:
    image = QtGui.QImage(output_size, QtGui.QImage.Format_ARGB32)
    image.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)

    canvas = image

# uncomment to hide background
#chart.setBackgroundBrush(brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.NoBrush))

# resize the chart, as otherwise the size/scaling of the axes etc.
# will be dependent on the size of the chart in the GUI
# this way, a consistent output size is enforced
original_size = chart.size()
chart.resize(output_rect.size())

painter = QtGui.QPainter()
painter.begin(canvas)

# enable antialiasing (painter must be active, set this after painter.begin())
# only affects PNG output
painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)

chart.scene().render(painter, source=output_rect, target=output_rect, mode=QtCore.Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio)
painter.end()

chart.resize(original_size)

if type(canvas) == QtGui.QImage:
    canvas.save(filename)
```

But if you're using python it might be easier to just go with matplotlib, which offers a lot more features and formats and can also be integrated into a PyQt-GUI.